# ¿Cómo enviar parametros al Metodo main?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando probar un ejemplo de la MSDN pero no logro entender cómo hacer para introducir parámetros al método MAIN.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    public class Reverse 
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args) 
        {

            // Comprobar si hay argumentos.
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage : Indexer <filename>");
                return;
            }

            // Comprobar si existe el archivo
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File " + args[0] + " not found.");
                return;
            }

            FileByteArray file = new FileByteArray(args[0]);
            long len = file.Length;

            // Intercambiar bytes en el archivo para invertirlo.
            for (long i = 0; i < len / 2; ++i) 
            {
               byte t;

                // Tenga en cuenta que al indizar la variable "file", se invoca al
                // indizador en la clase FileByteStream, que lee
                // y escribe los bytes en el archivo.
                t = file[i];
                file[i] = file[len - i - 1];
                file[len - i - 1] = t;
             }

            file.Close();
        } 
    }
```

En el primer `If` se comprueba si hay argumentos, pero como no los hay se sale del programa y termina. ¿Cómo se supone que debo enviar como parámetro el archivo que despues se comprueba en el siguiente `If`?

Gracias

Comment: Como le estas enviando los parametros al metodo main?

Comment: @Einer me parece que eso es justamente lo que no sabe hacer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La mayoría de los archivos ejecutables permiten recibir parámetros. Los parámetros se envían al momento de ejecutar el programa, como una lista separada por espacios.

Puedes probar por ejemplo con ipconfig, la herramienta para saber tu IP, la cual recibe múltiples parámetros para saber que mostrar.

En este caso, es lo mismo, al ejecutar tu programa, le envías como parámetro un nombre de archivo. Si no recibe el mismo, sale.

Para eso, no haces mas que en la linea de comandos hacer

```
Tuejecutable.exe "archivoamandar"
```

Y en ese caso, el parámetro es archivoamandar

En el caso de la IDE de visual studio, puedes hacer un click derechos sobre el proyecto (no la solución, si no el proyecto que genera el ejecutable), y presionar sobre propiedades. Una vez allí, en la pestaña debug, encontrarás lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda separar los argumentos con espacios, y en caso de que los mismos contengan espacios, ponerlos entre comillas.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado a la perfeccion.

Gracias a ti tambien, Pablo

Answer (score 1):

Si ejecutas tu programa desde consola se haría así:

```
C:\Reverse.exe "1" "2" "3"
```

Si lo haces así, al entrar a tu Main, vas a tener que args tiene 3 parámetros: args[0] = 1, args[1] = 2, args[0] = 3

Una cosa que veo en tu código es que si no lo ejecutas con 1 parámetro va a salir del programa, ya sean 0 parámetros, 2, 3... supongo que es porque sólo quieres aceptar un parámetro.